# When are C++ default constructors implicitly deleted?

Tags: c++, constructor, standards

Referencing [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor),

> If no user-declared constructors of any kind are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a default constructor as an inline public member of its class.

> If some user-declared constructors are present, the user may still force the automatic generation of a default constructor by the compiler that would be implicitly-declared otherwise with the keyword default.

This tells me when a default constructor for my class is declared (either by myself or by the compiler).

This does not tell me when there is guaranteed *no* default constructor. My reading of that article leaves open the possibility that the compiler could provide a default constructor anyways. Hence the existence of a default constructor might be implementation-dependent.

For example, according to my reading of the article, a default constructor might still be declared even if I provide a user-defined constructor (with arguments).

*Question:* when are default constructors guaranteed to be *not* defined? Is there any grey area where that is implementation-dependent?

I appreciate some sort-of-official reference on this. The standard says:

> A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X for which each parameter that is not a function
> parameter pack has a default argument (including the case of a constructor with no parameters). If there is
> no user-declared constructor for class X, a non-explicit constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared
> as defaulted (11.4). An implicitly-declared default constructor is an inline public member of its class.

In my reading, this leaves open the possibility that I declare a constructor but the compiler may or may not declare a default constructor.

```
class Foo { 
public:
// Is this one already declared?
// Foo();
Foo( int i );
}
```

Comment: No there is no gray area. You define a constructor of your own, a default constructor will no longer be generated for you. You can force one to be generated using default keyword. e.g. myclass { public : myclass() = default; };

Comment: In short: If you declare a constructor of any kind, then the compiler will not create a default constructor for you.

Comment: @PKramer: thanks. I am wondering whether that is anywhere official in writing?

Comment: Yes : http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf, page 248. 4) If there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a non-explicit constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted (11.4)

Comment: That says 'if' but not 'if and only if' -- possibly that is the reason of OP's doubts.

Comment: @CiaPan: exactly!

Comment: q.v. Howard Hinnant's [compiler implicitly declares](https://howardhinnant.github.io/smf.jpg) table, on his [How I declare my class any why](https://howardhinnant.github.io/classdecl.html) page.

Comment: @AlpinistKitten: The standard specifies behavior. *All* behavior. If the standard says "if A then B happens," then that's how it works. Unless the standard elsewhere says "if C then B happens", B only happens if A. There is no need for "if and only if" language.

Comment: The compiler also can't implicitly declare `int wombat;` in your class, although nothing in the Standard says it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, and in the edit to your question, [this Draft C++17 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) has the following:

> ##### 15.1 Constructors       [class.ctor]
>
> ⋮
> <sup>4</sup>    … If there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a non-explicit constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted.

I'm not sure how you interpret this as, in any way, ambiguous. We could express this in 'pseudo' C++ code as follows:

```cpp
bool user-declared_ctor;
//...
if (!user-declared_ctor) {
    Make_Implicit_Def_Ctor();
}
else {
    // Don't!
}
```

Or would you prefer that the **`if`** keyword in C++ were renamed to **`if_and_only_if`**?

Comment: To answer your last question, no, because that's not what the if-clause does by common understanding.